# How do I compile a C# Visual Studio solution on Windows for a Mac

Tags: c#, windows, macos, compilation

So I have a solution on Windows that I want to compile so that it works on Mac. How do I do this without actually having a Mac?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is your solution .net CORE?

Comment: I have compiled my code in .NET CORE but it outputs a .exe and some .dlls and a .pdb. Can any of these run on a mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better use Linux (or WSL) to run `dotnet publish` (as you'll need to call `chmod` to manipulate the execute permission). I have [a sample PowerShell script here](https://github.com/lextm/restructuredtext-antlr/blob/master/dist.server.ps1).

In short you need the following for your `executable` on .NET Core 3.1.

```
dotnet publish --self-contained -r osx-x64 -c release -o ..\output\darwin_x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true
Set-Location output
Set-Location darwin_x64
chmod a+x executable
Compress-Archive * -DestinationPath ..\darwin_x64.zip
Set-Location ..
```

However, this approach only targets console applications. Applications with user interface require much more effort to port to Mac, and you need a Mac in most cases.
    Set-Location ..

Answer (score 1):

I see you are a new contributor. Welcome!

My understanding is that iOS or MacOS code needs to be build on a Mac and that this is non-negotiable per policy made by Apple. Here is a current link that describes how to [pair your windows machine to a remote mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/) at which point the builds take place automatically.

You can even deploy over wireless. For example, the way I am set up, I build the project on my Windows machine which is paired over wireless to my MacBook Pro which deploys over wireless to my iPhone. Works great.

Another aspect of your question here is that while the logic of your app can be made portable by using NET Core for the code behind or better yet NET Standard, the sticking point is often that UI code is wildly platform specific.

Without expressing an opinion of whether it's a good thing or a bad thing, one approach that is supported in the Visual Studio 2019 Community free edition is Xamarin mobile cross platform development. (Can be included in your project with Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Essentials nuGet packages.) This way you can create UIs only one time using xaml that will work across devices.

I've used Xamarin for a number of years, and in my experience it's performing well for the Android/iOS/UWP apps that I've ported. I believe that Xamarin for MacOS is also online now but I haven't used it.

Your question is a good one, but pretty gigantic in scope. I hope this info will at least get you started in a direction!

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know you can just code for .NET core, but compilation must be done in a Mac